# why different theme color for preferencescreen on AOS 4.4 and 6.0

Tags: android, themes

why is the same app show different theme color for preferencescreen on android 4.4 and 6.0.

Below the snapshots from the devices.[image]

and on AOS ver: 6.0
[image]

below are the styles

*values* folder

@color/colorPrimary
        @color/colorPrimaryDark
        @color/colorAccent

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

and *values-21* folder

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Prefs" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: when using pre-lollipop you have to inject AppCompatCheckBox instead of normal checkboxes. Sorry, no time to write proper answer but you should be able to google off this.

Comment: @poss : cant use via resource file, throws    *exception:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox cannot be cast to android.preference.Preference*